# И снова о частице "бы"

Tags: пунктуация

Частое повторение частицы "бы" тут уже обсуждалось. Но как тогда перефразировать следующее предложение, чтобы "бы" в нем встречалось пореже: "...залив, который, если б не многочисленные морские суда у причалов, напоминал бы широкую реку..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это законное употребление, "бы" здесь в разных предложениях. Стилистическую шероховатость разрыва подчиненным предложением главного после слова "который" я здесь не рассматриваю, ограничиваясь грамматикой.

Но можно и перефразировать.

"...залив, который напоминал бы широкую реку, не будь многочисленных морских судов у причалов, ..."